# How rare is the Blood moon in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

I've been casually playing Terraria for some time. I really wanted the blood moon to spawn but I have been playing for some time and only one has appeared.

**How often do they appear?**

Comment: Make sure you have found at least one heart crystal, so your max HP is at least 120.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Terraria Gamepedia](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Blood_Moon):

> A Blood Moon will only occur if at least one player in the world has over 120 life, and only on nights when a moon is present (any night except a new moon). Given those criteria, a Blood Moon has a 1 in 9 chance (11.11%) of occurring.

Following the criteria above, there is a **1/9 chance (or 11.11%)** chance of a Blood Moon occurring.